# How does Shared Cache work in SQLite?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, caching

I still can't get my head around this.
I have a Application which runs multiple threads. Can someone enlighten me from the following scenario based question?

**SCENARIO**

- Thread 1 opens an SQLite Database connection, queries it, and thus
  caches what it has read inside Server Memory. Thread 1 then Closes
  the connection
- Then Thread 2 open the SQLite Database, performing almost similar
  query to Thread

**QUESTION :** Will thread 2 be able to access the cached data from Thread 1, ensuring a faster Query (eventhough Thread 1 has closed the connection)?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) says:

> If shared-cache mode is enabled and a [process] establishes multiple connections to the same database, the connections share a single data and schema cache.

In your scenario, there are never multiple connections at the same time, so nothing is shared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but in my case there are multiple connection.. but from two separate threads....

Comment: No, the first thread closes its connection before the second thread opens one.

Comment: Oh, so if Thread 1 remains open when thread 2 connects... and then thread 1 closes (but thead 2 remain open) ==> Is the cache still alive?

Comment: Yes, that would be "multiple connections to the same database".